# Getting routes associated with bus stops

Tags: mysql, sql, gtfs

I have GTFS data and I want to have information about routes departing from bus stop.

For particular stop I used this code:

```
select stops.stop_id, 
stops.stop_name, 
stops.stop_lat, 
stops.stop_lon, 
stops.zone_id, 
GROUP_CONCAT( distinct rt.route_short_name) as routes
from routes rt, trips tr, stop_times st, stops
where rt.route_id = tr.route_id
and tr.trip_id = st.trip_id
and st.stop_id = stops.stop_id
and st.stop_id = '$stop_id'
group by st.stop_id
```

But I want to achieve the same thing for multiple stops (ex. search result). I use simple LIKE method for search and to each row I would like to attach information about routes, like for single stop.

```
SELECT stop_id, stop_name, stop_lat, stop_lon, zone_id FROM stops WHERE stop_name LIKE '%$search_term%'
```

I will appreciate help as I don't know much about databases.

Thanks!

Comment: What sort of searching will you do? Name? Geographic proximity? It's necessary to figure that out before coding a search query.

Comment: If you replace "and st.stop_id = '$stop_id'" with "and stop_name LIKE '%$search_term%'", would that not do what you want?

Comment: I see you are abusing MySQL's feature off not naming your select columns within the group by this can result in wrong results.. http://www.dbasquare.com/2012/05/15/mysql-mistakes-do-you-use-group-by-correctly/